# class ui.showModalDialog throws LocalStorage Security exception when ‘Block Third-Party cookies’ is enabled in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace-add-ons

Currently in our application (Both Google editor add-on and Google Workspace add-on), we are using showModalDialog to load a different URL in an iFrame.
[Link](https://developers.google.com/appsscript/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)))
Here is the code snippet for the same:

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(‘top’).setWidth(700)
           .setHeight(620).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
           .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, “My Page”);
```

‘Top’ is a html page with iframe which hosts the URL. This modal dialog appears properly when user click on a button in HTML page / card interface page hosted on the sidebar of the add-on.  This works fine when ‘Allow all cookies’ is enabled.

The exception occurs only when user set ‘Block Third-Party cookies’ in chrome browser cookie settings.  After disabling Third-Party cookies, when user click on button in the sidebar, dialog appears and it couldn’t render the page and throws security exception.
I see the below local storage security exception in console logs of the browser.
[Error on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzY5p.png)

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

How do i fix this issue? Is there anyway to set cookie via storage API from google apps script?

Updated Code here and detailed description of the issue

We are trying to show our existing implementation of a file picker to maintain uniformity across the applications.
The way the communication between the iframe and the google App script is via Post Message. To trigger the iframe,
This is what I am trying
In editor add-ons,

1. Have a button on the HTML page and when the click event is triggered it communicates back to the .gs file where the below code is written in the function
2. In the Other Google Workspace add-on, We have a button added via a card interface and a callback function on this button executes the following function

```
    function() {
       var driveService = getDriveService();
        if(driveService.hasAccess()) {
            var driveService = getDriveService();
    var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('top').setWidth(700)
        .setHeight(620).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
        .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
         DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template, “Modal Title");
    } else {
      showSidebar()
    }
}
```

Inside top.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="getTargetURL()">
  <iframe id="iframe" style="width: 700px; height: 610px;" src='' frameborder='0'> </iframe>
   <script>
   var dialogToken = '';
   var src = '';
   function getTargetURL() {
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((success) => {
        dialogToken = encodeURIComponent(success['dialogToken']);
        src = url + dialog token; // which is almost similar to access token      
        frame = document.getElementById('iframe');
        frame.src = src;
      }).withFailureHandler(() => {
      }).fetchDialogToken()
   }
   window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
   function handleMessage(e) {
   if(e['data'] != undefined) {
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((success)=> {
       console.log('successfully saved the document' + JSON.stringify(success))
     }).withFailureHandler((error)=> {
       alert("unable to save the document" + JSON.stringify(error))
     }).saveDocument(e)
   } 
   }
   </script>
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

The appscript.json file

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Drive",
      "serviceId": "drive",
      "version": "v2"
    }],
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
      "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
      "version": "35"
    }]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "GWA for add-on",
      "logoUrl": " ",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#3b69f2",
        "secondaryColor": "#3b69f2"
      }
    },
    "docs": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onLoadFunction"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGranted"
      }
    },
    "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onLoadFunction"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGranted"
      }
    },
    "slides": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onLoadFunction"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGranted"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Please share a sample piece of code of your Apps Script Add-On without leaking *any sensitive data*. Also, what are you exactly want to achieve with this? Do you want to set a cookie with Apps Script? Display an iframe? Thanks ! :D

Comment: I am updating the question with the details. Please check

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, Any update on this?

Comment: Hi ! Could you also please share your ```appsscript.manifest``` file so that I can reproduce your behaviour as accurately as possible to get the same error message? Thanks !

Comment: Hi @MateoRandwolf, Have updated the file. 
Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: Hi ! So I have been trying unsuccessfully to run your Add-On with the code you provided as it seems it is not complete. My aim is to test this Add-On on my environment to see if I can also reproduce you behaviour and to further investigate it. Considering this, could you please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your Add-On without any sensitive data so that I can test it?